# How to change the fileName when upload in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

[image]

[image]

How to change the fileName when upload in Jmeter?
Like filename="D:\xxxx\log\JOU20200403.txt"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload a different file each time you execute the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler you can use a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) instead of hard-coding the filename parameter.

Once done you can either list the files you want to upload in a .csv file and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so each virtual user on each iteration will pick next file from the list.

Alternatively if you have a folder with the files you would like to upload you can use [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter/) plugin